# Unable to set Terminator as default Terminal in Ubuntu with Cinnamon Desktop

Tags: cinnamon, terminator

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 from the official website and installed terminator using APT and It worked! <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> started terminator.

Then I installed cinnamon desktop, rebooted and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> came up with the default terminal, not with terminator.

I changed the  priority to higher than the default emulator with `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator x-terminal-emulator /usr/bin/terminator 60`, this also didn't work.

`sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator` gives this table:

```
Selection    Path                             Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/terminator               60        auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper   40        manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/terminator               60        manual mode
```

What am I doing wrong? Is cinnamon interfering here?

Comment: I haven't used Cinnamon for years, so I am not sure of the exact workflow, but you should be able to remove the default Ctrl+Alt+T shortcut and then add a new Ctrl+Alt+T shortcut which will run `terminator`.  Another option could be completely uninstalling `gnome-terminal`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please enter the following in a terminal :

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec /usr/bin/terminator

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec-arg "-x"
```

You might have to enter the following line as well

```
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec /usr/bin/terminator
```

Answer (score 0):

**Changing the bin file to the one you want for the keyboard shortcut works for me.**

Go to:
`Keyboard -> Application Shortcuts`

Then change the **command** tab for terminal to -> `/usr/bin/terminator`
Or whatever the path to your binary program. Peace out.

[image: Keyboard menu]