# Ubuntu 20.04 use terminator instead of gnome terminal to run default applications

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal, gnome-shell, terminator

I've already set up terminator so that `ctrl-alt-t` runs terminator instead of gnome-terminal. However, whenever I want to open a terminal application like vim from shell-search, it still uses gnome-terminal.

I also want to make it so that running "open in terminal" in nautilus, opens terminator instead of gnome-terminal.

I've already set my default terminal app to terminator with `sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator`. But it still does not work.

I have been trying to find a solution to this for quite some time but haven't found the answer anywhere.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to set Terminator as default Terminal in Ubuntu with Cinnamon Desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1261901/unable-to-set-terminator-as-default-terminal-in-ubuntu-with-cinnamon-desktop) This should also apply to GNOME desktop.

Comment: @User24601 I tried that but I don't seem to have something called default-applications under org.gnome.desktop when using dconf. Also, the running the command `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec /usr/bin/terminator`, though it does not give any errors, does not seem to do anything. So, yeah that is not working for me.